# Google Maps API calls failing on Android, "automated queries" error

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm retrieving addresses from cooridnates using the Google API with the following method:

```
public static String[] getFromLocation(double lat, double lng, int retries) {

    String address = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), 
            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%1$f,%2$f&sensor=false&language=" 
                    + Locale.getDefault(), lat, lng);

    String[] res = new String[3];

    String addressLine = "";
    String locality = "";
    String country = "";
    String json = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
        json = jsonResults.toString();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);


        if ("OK".equalsIgnoreCase(jsonObject.getString("status"))) {
            JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            if (results.length() > 0) {
                JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(0);
                //Address addr = new Address(Locale.getDefault());

                JSONArray components = result.getJSONArray("address_components");
                String streetNumber = "";
                String route = "";
                for (int a = 0; a < components.length(); a++) {
                    JSONObject component = components.getJSONObject(a);
                    JSONArray types = component.getJSONArray("types");
                    for (int j = 0; j < types.length(); j++) {
                        String type = types.getString(j);
                        if (type.equals("locality")) {
                            locality = component.getString("long_name");
                        } else if (type.equals("street_number")) {
                            streetNumber = component.getString("long_name");
                        } else if (type.equals("route")) {
                            route = component.getString("long_name");
                        } else if (type.equals("country")) {
                            country = component.getString("long_name");
                        }
                    }
                }
                addressLine = route + " " + streetNumber;

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception:", e);
        LogsToServer.send(my_id, e);
        if (json != null) LogsToServer.send(my_id, json);
        System.out.println("retries: " + retries);
        if (retries > 0){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return getFromLocation(lat, lng, retries-1);
        }
    }

    res[0] = addressLine;
    res[1] = locality;
    res[2] = country; 

    return res;
}
```

The problem is that I very often get the exception:

```
03-12 23:54:01.387: E/GetAddressDetails(25248): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=48,2&sensor=false&language=en_GB
03-12 23:54:01.387: E/GetAddressDetails(25248):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
03-12 23:54:01.387: E/GetAddressDetails(25248):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
03-12 23:54:01.387: E/GetAddressDetails(25248):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
```

If I launch the method with 4 retries, they may all fail, or sometimes after 2 or 3 I get the address. Do you know why it fails so often? When I access the same site in my browser I always get the page without errors!

EDIT: I checked the error message returned by Google and it goes like this:

```
We're sorry... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.
```

Is it a joke? Automated queries? Isn't it the whole purpose of APIs to be called by automatic processes?
Also, this happens from many phones and started yesterday. How does google know that all the requests come from the same app?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get address from cooridnates, you can use `Geocoder` api.

I used following code in my app to `get the city name`:

```
private double mLongitude; // current longitude
private double mLatitude; // current latitude
private String mCityName; // output cityName

private void getCityName() {
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(mLatitude, mLongitude, 1);
            if (addresses.size() != 0) {
                mCityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                mCityName = mCityName.replaceAll("[\\d.]", "");
                Log.d(TAG + "!!!!!!!!!!!", mCityName);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If you want get `whole address`, as I changed a little bit, just do this way:

```
private double mLongitude; // current longitude
private double mLatitude; // current latitude
private String mAddress; // output address

private void getAddress() {
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(mLatitude, mLongitude, 1);
            if (addresses.size() != 0) {
                mAddress = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + " " +
                        addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " " +
                        addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                //mAddress = mAddress.replaceAll("[\\d.]", "");
                Log.d(TAG + "!!!!!!!!!!!", mAddress);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes of course, but it does not work in all countries and all phones (even recent ones) for some reason, so I still need a fallback method.